# Crash my Android app in HttpResponse response Code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to get the response code for the HttpReponse.
I have changed the method for getting the response but it is not working.

Before I used this try & catch:
(url is parameter for function)

```
try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);

        if (params != null) {
            method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpclient .execute(method);

        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

        return result;
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

But this code gave me a runtime error in `HttpResponse response = httpclient .execute(method);`

So I changed my code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

String      username;
String      password;
InputStream is     = null;
String      result = null;
String      line   = null;
int         code;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    final EditText usernamefield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_reg);
    final EditText passwordfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_reg);
    Button reg_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
    reg_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            username = usernamefield.getText().toString();
            password = passwordfield.getText().toString();
            insert();
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usernamefield.getText().toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordfield.getText().toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "insert"));

        }
    });

}


public void insert()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "insert"));

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.10/ferdos/service.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }

    try
    {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code = (json_data.getInt("code"));

        if (code == 1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}}
```

Please help me with this code to solve my problem.

Comment: Use Async task, please follow this example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: why dont work this method?

Comment: You did not ensure Asynchronous response, So when time out/delay happen in HttpResponse, you could face app crush/ANRs issue

Comment: I cant use asyc task If it is possible for you , please edit my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thats what](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting) Google says.

> To avoid creating an unresponsive UI, don't perform network operations on the UI thread. By default, Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher requires you to perform network operations on a thread other than the main UI thread; if you don't, a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown.

You need to execute your HTTP requests in separate thread. This can be done in a `AsyncTask.`

In your case you need to update UI after the downloading is finished. Use a listener to notify the UI thread

```
public interface ResultsListener {
    public void onResultsSucceeded(String result);
}
```

[This is an example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) from Google developers guide. I edited it and it calls the listener when the result is finished.

```
 private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {

      public void setOnResultsListener(ResultsListener listener) {
           this.listener = listener;
      }

      protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             String httpResult = // Do your HTTP requests here
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return httpResult;
     }

     // use this method if you need to show the progress (eg. in a progress bar in your UI)
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }
     // this method is called after the download finished.
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result);
         listener.onResultsSucceded(result);
     }
 }
```

Now you can execute the task by calling `new HttpRequestTask().execute(url)` in your Activity. Your activity needs to implement the `ResultsListener`. Inside the `onResultsSucceeded` method you can update your UI elements.

You see, you can use the AsyncTask in your example pretty well. You just need some reformatting of your code.

Comment: i do this method but dont woring

Comment: can you explain in more detail what is not working? Do you get an exception or anything else?

Comment: please check my code... this code is not any reaction and not insert in database are you think my code is true?

Comment: @kamal, you have to pass the username and password data in the constructor of the AsycTask. With your code, the password and username will always be empty

Comment: @kamal, I edited your code example in your post below

Answer (score 0):

I use AsyncTask but dont working again
please check my code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

EditText editusername;
EditText editpassword;
String   username;
String   password;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    editusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_reg);
    editpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_reg);

    Button reg_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
    reg_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            username = editusername.getText().toString();
            password = editpassword.getText().toString();
            new RegisterAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
}


class RegisterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private void postData(String username, String password) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myurl");

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "insert"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  " + e.toString());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        postData(username, password);
        return null;
    }
}}
```